# Как в bash сделать с помощью imagemagic анимацию из одной картинки?

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Нужно используя команду convert в imagemagic написать скрипт, который бы конвертировал картинку в гифку, которая бы состояла из одной картинки, которая поворачивается на введенный пользователем угол в течение заданного времени.

`convert -rotate "$2" "$1" -loop 0 "$3".gif` - конвертирует переданную картинку в  .gif, поворачивая на угол "$2" и новый файл называет "$3". Не нашла нигде информацию, как заставить делать такие повороты циклически и в течении времени, которое тоже передается как аргумент. 
Пожалуйста, помогите!

Comment: Сразу делаем несколько картиток, потом объединяем в анимированную (convert -loop 0 -delay 100 in1.gif in2.gif in3.gif out.gif)

Comment: Это какая-то учебная задача? Потому как это достигается обычно другими средствами.

Comment: да, это учебная задача. В начале изучения bash